# No-break space causing problems in Xcode

Tags: xcode, unicode

Quite often when I code in Xcode, I type no-break space (Option + Space / Option + Shift + Space) especially before or after square brackets or curly braces. This causes Xcode to give warning:

```
invalid character in source file
```

Is there any way  to prevent this behavior, as it is really annoying and rarely necessary? I tried to look for an answer in Xcode menus and Google but didn't find anything proper.

Comment: Here: http://superuser.com/a/142573

Answer (score 5):

I also had that problem (xCode 7.2) and found a workaround by assigning Option+Space and Option+Shift+Space to "Make Text Writing Direction Left ToRight" in Xcode

- Preferences (menu)
- Key Bindings(section)
- Default(drop down)
- Text(tab)
- Writing Direction(section)
- Make Text Writing Direction Left ToRight(command)
- Double-click and use (+) on the right to add key bindings.

You could assign them to any other command that doesn't have a useful effect for you.

It will make it seem that the space bar is not responding when you accidentally hold the modifier keys but that's much less of a time waster than the compilation errors.

Comment: I don't get why this error is even happening. It certainly shouldn't be. Is it because of pasting text into a playground?

Comment: It happens on keyboards that require frequent use of the option key to get to brackets (or other characters).  When you're typing fast and follow the bracket with a space, you sometimes end up pressing Option-space and this creates an invisible invalid character in your source file.   The workaround is to assign a different meaning to option-space so that it does not insert the invalid characters.

Comment: In my case I had set a shortcut key to bind manual execution. It was entering the DC2 ASCII character. I was able to see the character once I pasted the code into a text editor. I believe Xcode can be set to show invisible characters. Anyhow your answer gave me a good hint.

Answer (score 1):

Alt+Space command creates a special hidden character in Xcode files. You can see details of bug [here](http://www.openradar.me/31817942).

For more details about solution checkout my answer on [Xcode - Invalid character in source file (Replace “ ” with “ ”)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151396/1419745)

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this by binding `Cancel (Cancellation)` to Esc.