# Comparing a variable of optional enum type with two particular cases in an if statement

Tags: swift, if-statement, enums, option-type

I define a Swift enumeration as follows:

```
enum Direction {
    case up
    case down
    case left
    case right
}
```

Then I create and initiate a variable of this type:

```
var direction: Direction = .up
```

and a variable of the respective *optional* type:

```
var optionalDirection: Direction? = .up
```

Now I want to check against particular cases in the condition of an `if` statement:

---

#### 1. Compare optional with a single case ✅

```
if optionalDirection == .up {
    print("Optional direction is 'up'.")
}
```

prints:

> `Optional direction is 'up'.`

---

#### 2. Compare non-optional with two cases ✅

```
if direction == .down || direction == .up {
    print("Direction is vertical.")
}
```

prints:

> `Direction is vertical.`

---

#### 3. Compare optional with two cases ❌

However,

```
if optionalDirection == .down || optionalDirection == .up {
    print("Optional direction is vertical.")
}
```

throws an error:

> `error: invalid character in source file`
>   `error: expected '{' after 'if' condition`

---

### Why does example **3** fail?

Is there a way to fix it without using the rather unintuitive pattern matching syntax (`if case ...`)?

Comment: You example 3 compiles fine in my Xcode. – *"invalid character in source file"* means that there is probably some (invisible) control character. Select "Show invisible characters" in the Xcode editor or rewrite the line.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but there are no invisible / invalid characters in the file. I just wrote for testing this scenario and just checked again with "Show Invisibles".

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and cannot reproduce the issue in Xcode 8 or Xcode 9 beta 3.

Comment: I tested it in a playground. It is working for me aswell.

Comment: Xcode 8.3.3 compiles just fine.  Try and re-type the example manually on a clean file.

Comment: @MartinR: You are correct. It _was_ an invalid character that I didn't even see with "Show Invisibles" enabled: Right after typing `||` I must have still had the option key pressed down when typing the white space (German keyboard layout). Thus, a special white space with a different unicode was inserted that caused the error. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Thank you guys for your support! @MartinR: You may post this as an answer if you like.

Comment: "Remove the invisible characters" is not a helpful answer for future readers searching for "Comparing a variable of optional enum type" :) – Voting to close as off-topic (simple typographic error).

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. Yes, it's just a typo but one that is difficult to find. Someone else with the same keyboard layout might easily run into the same issue and an answer to this question might solve the problem for him or her.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056391/xcode-invalid-character-in-source-file-replace-with.