# Array inside struct

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, constructor

I have two structs. The first one has only primitive types, and the second one has a type of the first one and another primitive types. My problem is when I try to create a new instance of the second one. This is my example code:

```
struct Jugador{
    var nombre:String=""
    var posicion:String=""
    var dorsal:Int=0

    //Constructor
    init(nombre:String,posicion:String,dorsal:Int){
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.posicion=posicion
        self.dorsal=dorsal
    }
}


struct Equipo{
    //variable estatica registrar equipo
    static var registrar:Int=0

    var nombre:String=""
    var estadio:String=""
    var jugadores:[Jugador]=[Jugador]()

    //Constructor con jugadores
    init(nombre:String,estadio:String,jugadores:[Jugador]){
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.estadio=estadio
        self.jugadores=jugadores
        //al crear un equipo lo registro
        Equipo.registrarEquipo()
    }
    //funcion que registra a un equipo
    static func registrarEquipo(){
        registrar+=1
    }
}

var jugador1=Jugador(nombre:"portero",posicion:"portero",dorsal:1)
var jugador2=Jugador(nombre:"lateral",posicion:"defensa",dorsal:2)
var jugadores1=[jugador1,jugador2]
var equipo1=Equipo(nombre:"equipo1",estadio:"estadio1",jugadores:jugadores1)
```

Sorry, my error is in this line:

```
var equipo1=Equipo(nombre:"equipo1",estadio:"estadio1",jugadores:jugadores1)
```

this is the message
    Invalid character in source file

Sorry for spanish names and comments, it is just an example which I am doing to learn about structs

Comment: For Spanish, https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: What error do you get? "'=' must have consistent whitespace on both sides"? Remove spaces before `Equipo` to make it compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: PlaygroundScreen]

I have verified your results, but it is giving correct results. Find screenshot

Here is code snippet:

```
struct Jugador{
    var nombre:String
    var posicion:String
    var dorsal:Int

    //Constructor
    init(nombre:String,posicion:String,dorsal:Int){
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.posicion=posicion
        self.dorsal=dorsal
    }
}


struct Equipo{
    //variable estatica registrar equipo
    static var registrar:Int=0

    var nombre:String=""
    var estadio:String=""
    var jugadores:[Jugador]=[Jugador]()

    //Constructor con jugadores
    init(nombre:String,estadio:String,jugadores:[Jugador]){
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.estadio=estadio
        self.jugadores=jugadores
        //al crear un equipo lo registro
        Equipo.registrarEquipo()
    }
    //funcion que registra a un equipo
    static func registrarEquipo(){
        registrar+=1
    }
}

var jugador1 = Jugador(nombre:"portero",posicion:"portero",dorsal:1)
var jugador2 = Jugador(nombre:"lateral",posicion:"defensa",dorsal:2)
var jugadores1 = [jugador1,jugador2]
var equipo1 = Equipo(nombre:"equipo1",estadio:"estadio1",jugadores:jugadores1)

print(equipo1)
```

And here is the output in Playground. Executed it in Swift 3.1

```
Equipo(nombre: "equipo1", estadio: "estadio1", jugadores: [__lldb_expr_7.Jugador(nombre: "portero", posicion: "portero", dorsal: 1), __lldb_expr_7.Jugador(nombre: "lateral", posicion: "defensa", dorsal: 2)])
```

Comment: Yes that is true... I don't know way but i copy and paste your snippet and now it woks... thank you very much

Comment: compare the code, may be there would be some special character was added, which could be giving error. also plz accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really hard to read. You should consider following the generally accepted best practices and add some spacings. Besides that the principle of your code is almost right.

As far as I'm concerned, Structs are usually not intended to be mutated so you also should consider making the internal vars lets if you don't need to change them. Here's an example:

```
struct Jugador {
    let nombre: String
    let posicion: String
    let dorsal: Int

    //Constructor
    init(nombre: String, posicion: String, dorsal: Int) {
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.posicion = posicion
        self.dorsal = dorsal
    }
}


struct Equipo {

    static var registrar: Int = 0

    let nombre: String
    let estadio: String
    let jugadores: [Jugador]

    //Constructor con jugadores
    init(nombre: String, estadio: String, jugadores: [Jugador]){
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.estadio = estadio
        self.jugadores = jugadores
        Equipo.registrar += 1
    }
}
let jugador1 = Jugador(nombre: "portero", posicion: "portero", dorsal: 1)
let jugador2 = Jugador(nombre: "lateral", posicion: "defensa", dorsal: 2)
let jugadores1 = [jugador1, jugador2]
let equipo1 = Equipo(nombre: "equipo1", estadio: "estadio1", jugadores: jugadores1)

equipo1.jugadores.first?.nombre
```

Comment: struct supports `var`

Comment: I know. Thats why I said that they usually are not intended to be mutated to reduce the risk of side effects. The other day I saw a very interesting talk about immutable structs and their benefits. Unfortunately I cant find it anymore but if you google for benefits of immutable structs in swift, you will surely find a few videos/posts. You should check it out! :)

Comment: In above example, if we will use `registrar` object only as var, then `static func registrarEquipo()` method becomes `mutating func registrarEquipo()`

Answer (score 0):

The "Invalid character in source file" error is not really related to your code.  Most of the time it is caused by an invisible character (non breaking space) that you accidentally type by pressing option+Space.   On non US keyboards (French in my case, Spanish in yours), you often have to use the option key to access some of the special characters.  When you are typing fast, this will sometimes cause you to press the space bar before releasing the option key.

I found a workaround for this.  See this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34696032/5237560

In a nutshell, I reconfigured the Option+Space shortcut to something that would not produce any character in the source file.